# How to get the unique values from column to row

Tags: unix, awk, solaris

I have a input file like:

```
> cat test_mfd_1
16,281474976750348
17,281474976750348
16,281474976750348
17,281474976750348
16,281474976749447
17,281474976749447
16,281474976749447
17,281474976749447
```

And I need the output like:

```
281474976750348 16,17
281474976749447 16,17
```

Column 2 and 1 both have duplicated values. But as o/p it should find the unique values in column 2 and print all corresponding unique values as in row.

I am using awk and i get the o/p like below.

```
awk -F, '{a[$2]=$1;} END {for(i in a) print i" "a[i];}' test_mfd_1
281474976749447 17
281474976750348 17
```

I am not able to print all unique values from column 1 in front of column 2

Comment: Use the `{}` button in the editor or prepend data and code with four spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Perl

```
$ cat jeevan.txt
16,281474976750348
17,281474976750348
16,281474976750348
17,281474976750348
16,281474976749447
17,281474976749447
16,281474976749447
17,281474976749447

$ perl -F, -lane ' $kv{$F[1]}{$F[0]}++; END { while(my($x,$y) = each(%kv)) { print "$x ",join(",",keys %$y) } }' jeevan.txt
281474976749447 16,17
281474976750348 16,17
```

or

```
$ perl -F, -lane ' $kv{$F[1]}{$F[0]}++; END { print "$_ ",join(",",keys %{$kv{$_}}) for(keys %kv) } ' jeevan.txt
281474976749447 16,17
281474976750348 16,17
```

or

```
$ perl -F, -lane ' push @{$kv{$F[1]}},$F[0]; END { for(keys %kv) { %p=map{ $_ => 1} @{$kv{$_}} ; print "$_ ",join(",", keys %p) } } ' jeevan.txt
281474976749447 17,16
281474976750348 16,17
```

or

```
$ perl -F, -lane ' push @{$kv{$F[1]}},$F[0]; END { for my $a (keys %kv) { @p=grep{ !$s{$a}{$_}++ } @{$kv{$a}} ; print "$a ",join(",", @p) } } ' jeevan.txt
281474976749447 16,17
281474976750348 16,17
```

or

```
$ perl -F, -lane ' push @{$kv{$F[1]}},$F[0]; END { for my $a (keys %kv) { print "$a ",join(",", grep{ !$s{$a}{$_}++ } @{$kv{$a}}) } } ' jeevan.txt
281474976750348 16,17
281474976749447 16,17
```

Since this resembles SQL, you can use sqlite also

```
$ cat ./sqllite_unique.sh
#!/bin/sh
sqlite3 << EOF
create table t1(a,b);
.separator ','
.import $1 t1
select b|| ' ' || group_concat(distinct a) from t1 group by b;
EOF

$ ./sqllite_unique.sh jeevan.txt
281474976749447 16,17
281474976750348 16,17
```

Comment: Thanks .. It helped me.

Comment: glad that it helped you.. please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 2):

Using [`GNU Datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/datamash.html):

```
$ datamash --sort -t, -g 2 unique 1 < file
281474976749447,16,17
281474976750348,16,17
```

If you insist on the space:

```
$ datamash --sort -t, -g 2 unique 1 < file | sed 's/,/ /'
281474976749447 16,17
281474976750348 16,17
```

Comment: Oooer. That's a nifty program.

Answer (score 1):

For GNU awk:

```
awk -F, '{a[$2][$1]} END {for(i in a) {printf i; first=1; for (j in a[i])  if (first) {printf " " j; first=0;} else printf "," j; print ""} }' test_mfd_1
#=> 281474976749447 16,17
#=> 281474976750348 16,17
```

Just improved your attempt.
The idea is to use two-dimension array, and a inner `for` loop.
`printf` won't print newline, so use `print ""` to append a new line at last.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another. It appends `$1` values comma-separated to `a[$2]` but uses `match()` first to check that the value isn't there already:

```
$ awk -F, '{
    a[$2]=a[$2] (match(a[$2],"(^|,)" $1 "($|,)")?"":(a[$2]==""?"":",")$1)
} 
END {
    for(i in a)
        print i,a[i]
} ' file
281474976749447 16,17
281474976750348 16,17
```

Explained a bit:

- `a[$2]=a[$2] (...` append to array
- `match(a[$2],"(^|,)" $1 "($|,)")?""` null if `match` finds a matching value
- `:(a[$2]==""?"":",")$1)` or a comma if needed and the value

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `Perl`:

```
$ perl -F, -lanE '$HoH{$F[1]}{$F[0]}++; 
                  END{for (keys %HoH) {
                         say "$_ ", join(", ", keys %{$HoH{$_}}); }}' file
281474976749447 16, 17
281474976750348 17, 16
```

Here is an awk:

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$2][$1]} 
           END{ for (e in a){
                  s=""
                  for (x in a[e]) s=s?s ", " x:x
                  print e, s}}' file
281474976749447 16, 17
281474976750348 16, 17
```

NOTE: Since both the `awk` and the `perl` use an associative array, the order printed will likely be different than the order the elements are encountered in the file.

Comment: which awk is this?.. I get syntax error $ awk -F, '{a[$2][$1]++ } ' jeevan.txt
awk: {a[$2][$1]++ }
awk:       ^ syntax error

Comment: @stack0114106  That `++` in what you show isn't in their post (mixed up with Perl?) -- _that_ would be illegal.  Their code runs for me.

Comment: @stack0114106 Ok .. i suggest then removing (all) these comments?

Answer (score 0):

`sort` assisted `awk`

```
$ sort -t, -u -k2 -k1,1 file | 
  awk -F, '{a[$2]=a[$2] sep[$2] $1; sep[$2]=FS} END{for(k in a) print k,a[k]}'

281474976749447 16,17
281474976750348 16,17
```

sep is for lazy separator initialization to skip the first one.

Comment: since the file is sorted, you can compare prev and current record and print them as you read the lines ````sort -t, -u -k2 -k1,1 file | awk -F, '{ if(prev!=$2) { x=NR>1?"\n":""; printf("%s%s %s",x,$2,$1) } else { printf(",%s",$1) } prev=$2 } END { print "" }'````